# Flaw in evaluating $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\frac{P(x)}{5(x-1)}\right)^x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

There was this question asked yesterday here: 
Link: [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x→∞}\left(\frac{P(x)}{5(x-1)}\right)^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821608/evaluating-limit-lim-x-to-infty-left-dfracpx5x-1-rightx)

> Consider $P(x)= ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ and $P(2)=9$.
>   Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of the equation $P(x)=0$.
>
> If $\alpha \to \infty$ and $P'(3)= 5$, then $\lim_{x\to
>  \infty}\left(\dfrac{P(x)}{5(x-1)}\right)^x$ is ?

The answer is:

> $e^{\frac 45}$

---

I gave a thought to it and this is what I did:

> If $\alpha \to \infty$ and $\alpha$ is a root of $P(x)$, then for $x \to \infty$, $P(x) \to 0$.
>
> Also, as $x \to \infty$, the denominator $5(x-1) \to \infty$.
>
> Therefore, $\dfrac {P(x)}{5(x-1)} \to 0$. And hence the whole limit asked in the question tends to zero.

There is a flaw in my reasoning. I am trying to find it. Is that flaw that solving this limit part by part is illegal? Or, is it something else? I am still learning it, any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why is the first sentence true? (If $\alpha \to \infty$ and ...)

Comment: The condition $\alpha \to \infty$ is really unclear to me.

Comment: @sku I said that because the question mentions that $\alpha$ is a root of the equation and it tends to infinity.

Comment: @gimusi Yes, I am confused too. I think you might find more on the link I attached, the original question. They say that if one root of quadratic is infinity, the equation becomes linear.

Comment: @IceInkberry I really doubt that the equation becomes linear if one root tends to infinity.

Comment: @IceInkberry With this assumption the limit becomes trivial but it is really a strange assumption.

Comment: I doubt it as well.

Comment: @Ice Refer this answer by heropup on the main question: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2822416/310635)

Comment: Exactly @samjoe if $x=\alpha$, the limit is zero. While wandering in the chat I had also mentioned about the infinities $x$ and $\alpha$, if they are comparable or not. Interesting. Thankyou for sharing the link as I didn't update myself with that question's answers.

Comment: Yeah this answer  was similar to your thought process :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your reasoning is rooted, so to speak, in the fact that the problem, as stated both here and in the original link, is very poorly posed.  It barely makes sense to talk about the limit of a polynomial as one of its roots tends to infinity, and whatever that notion means, it's absent from the expression $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(P(x)\over5(x-1)\right)^x$.  I suspect what's really meant is the following *double* limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}(a(\alpha)x^2+b(\alpha)x+c(\alpha))\over5(x-1) \right)^x$$

where $a=a(\alpha),b=b(\alpha),c=c(\alpha)$ are (the unique) solutions of the system of equations

$$\begin{align}
\alpha^2a+\alpha b+c&=0\qquad\text{i.e., }P(\alpha)=0\\
4a+2b+c&=9\qquad\text{i.e., }P(2)=9\\
6a+b&=5\qquad\text{i.e., }P'(3)=5
\end{align}$$

In other words, before you take the limit as $x$ goes to infinity, you have to *solve* for the coefficients of $P$ as *functions* of $\alpha$, then take the limit of what you get as $\alpha$ goes to infinity, and only then take the limit of what's left as an expression in the variable $x$.  The [answer by heropup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2821608/evaluating-lim-limits-x%E2%86%92%E2%88%9E-left-fracpx5x-1-rightx/2822416#2822416) at the original, linked question, discusses all this.

As for what's wrong in your reasoning, it has a certain superficial logic to it. Indeed, when writing a limit expression, you can use any variable you like, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}P(\alpha)$, at which point one is tempted to say that, since $\alpha$ is a root of $P$, which we want to take to infinity, we have $$\lim_{x\to\infty}P(x)=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}P(\alpha)=\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}0=0$$

The trick is, when picking a dummy variable to express a limit (or a sum, or whatever), you're not supposed to pick a variable that's already been assigned a meaning.  So when I said you can use any variable you like, that was a lie; there are rules that limit, so to speak, how you can express the taking of a limit. Usually the restrictions are obvious; in this case they're not, but that's mostly because of how poorly posed the problem is.